# Executing script when user connects via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'd like to create an interface when a specific user connects via ssh, for example:

User: xxx

```
ssh xxx@10.10.10.10
```

Interface:

```
1. Configuration
2. Status
3. Reboot
...
```

In other words, It needs to run a script when a specific user connects. I'd like to generate an interface for the user, as the Clouds do.

I don't need the script, I just want to know a way to execute a script when the user connects, instead he executes the script manually.

Comment: Set their shell to your script?

Comment: No, I just need to know how can I run a script when a user connects

Comment: actually @L3viathan has already answered your question.

Comment: Call it from their `~/.bash_login`

Comment: It works !!!! Ty for your tip.

Comment: If you set their shell (in /etc/passwd or via chsh), you could set their shell to your script, and then when they log in there is no command line, just your script. 

You may have to add your script path to /etc/shells for this to work, ymmv.

Comment: Keith, how could I do that?    xxx:x:1001:1001::/home/xxx:/bin/bash